# Flexbox behavior - Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a Flexbox and a table together. The output displays differently on Firefox than on Google Chrome and Safari. I have observed that on Google Chrome and Safari, the td elements wrap. Also, the max-width of each td does not exceed 50%. However, on Firefox, these styling rules are ignored (even though when I go to the code console, they aren't crossed out, which means they should be respected by the browser). On Firebox, when I shrink the window, the images shrink, but they never wrap.

This is less about whether using a table is a best practice or not. Can someone explain why this behavior varies between browsers even though all these browsers ostensibly support flexboxes. I tried the moz prefix, but it didn't work. I've checked [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) and the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) on flexboxes, and both indicate that Flexboxes are fully supported.

These's the CSS:

```
tr
{
    margin: 0;

    display: flex;  
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-content: center;
}

td
{
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 50%;

    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;

    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><a href=""  target="_blank"><img src="../images/gifs/gummo.gif" /></a></td>
          <td>
              <div id="gummo-quote" class="gif-copy">
              <p>Lorem ipsum etc.</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum etc.</p>
            </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: You don't need the vendor prefixes.

Comment: ..and why use `flexbox` on a table of all things...that's illogical on the face of it.

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar issue, for using a table, it differs on FF and Chrome, did you get a solution for this?